# Why am I getting this error on mariadb installation?

Tags: mariadb

I am trying to follow [this article](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-install-mariadb-on-rhel8-centos8/) and `systemctl start mariadb.service` gives me

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xeu mariadb.service" for details.
```

`journalctl -xeu mariadb.service` gives me

```
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit mariadb.service has exited.
░░
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
Jul 18 09:29:53 centos-4gb-fsn1-2 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ The unit mariadb.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 18 09:29:53 centos-4gb-fsn1-2 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 11.0.2 database server.
░░ Subject: A start job for unit mariadb.service has failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://access.redhat.com/support
░░
░░ A start job for unit mariadb.service has finished with a failure.
░░
░░ The job identifier is 2466 and the job result is failed.
```

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Make sure of your directory permissions. If it's trying to write something at startup, and failing, you'll see this sort of cryptic error.

Comment: Maybe selinux based problem? Check the logs.

Comment: Since `systemd`/`journalctl` can only see that the process exited with non-zero status, you would want to check the `mariadb` logs for any further information on that process.

Comment: @K-attila- you were right, it was selinux. I disabled it.

Comment: Anyway, it can run in selinux environment....

Comment: @GracefulRestart I'm now getting `Could not open mysql.plugin table: "Unknown storage engine 'Aria'". Some plugins may be not loaded` and `Failed to initialize plugins.`

Comment: Is this a fresh install of MariaDB or do you have an exiting database you are trying to work with?  If you are using a previously existing database, further information could be useful such as what database software and version was the database last working under?  If you do not have a previous database, have you tried starting with a fresh, empty database?

Comment: Okay, new info. mariadb daemon was using up port 3306 so I had to uninstall and reinstall it because kill -9 didn't work. Anyway, the good thing is `systemctl restart mariadb.service` isn't giving out any errors but right now I can't get it to create a sock file. Should I give this new info in an answer or ask a new question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, I wound up uninstalling mariadb and installing mysql because the same thing kept happening every time I attempted to install mariadb.